# Mock a method with bool as argument and return a List<> with Moq

Tags: c#, .net, mocking, moq

In my test, I defined as data a `List<IUser>` with some record in.

I'd like setup a moq the methode `GetList`, this method receive a `bool` as parameter. I'd like in return the `IUser` list where `IsValid` is true.

I tried this :

```
Mock<IUsers> mockUserRepository = new Mock<IUsers>();

mockUserRepository.Setup(mr => mr.GetList(It.IsAny<bool>()))
    .Returns((bool i) => _users.Select(x => x.IsValid == i));
```

But I get this error : `cannot convert List<bool> to List<IUser>`

```
class User : IUser
{
   public bool IsValid { get; set; }
}

interface IUser
{
   bool IsValid { get; set; }
}

interface IUsers
{
    List<IUser> GetList(bool isActive);
}
```

Comment: I've removed unrelated code... feel free to revert.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to *return the IUser list where IsValid is true*, when you should return a list of `IUser`, not a collection of `bool`, so use `Where` to filter the list instead of `Select`.

```
// returns IEnumerable<boolean>
.Returns((bool i) => _users.Select(x => x.IsValid == i));
```

should be

```
// returns List<IUser>
.Returns((bool i) => _users.Where(x => x.IsValid == i).ToList());
```